# XCode 8 Linker (ld) suppress warnings

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, linker

I am attempting to suppress all linker warnings on a particular target of a particular project. I added the following line to my config file:

```
WARNING_LDFLAGS = -w
```

However, there is no '-w' emitted in the ld call that XCode runs. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question. Apparently `WARNING_LDFLAGS` is the wrong option. When I used `OTHER_LDFLAGS` it worked.

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -w
```